# Peculiar colloquial use of « niveau »

Tags: expressions

In conversation, I have heard one of my colleagues using the noun « niveau » in a way that seems to deviate from its usual meaning:

> Hm... **Niveau mariage**, elle sait tout à fait de quoi elle parle...

The person in question was dishing out advice on everything marriage, even though she herself is far from being marriage material... Then, my colleague whispered as a joking, sarcastic jab that:

> {My interpretation}: She’s the last person I’d  turn to for advice, ***when it comes to*** marriage...

At least, this is how I interpreted her remark. I wonder if this particular use of « niveau » corresponds to "when it comes to" or something similar? How do you use  « niveau » like this in other examples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your interpretation is right, but the sarcastic aspect is not necessarily a part of the expression (in your example it seems to be). I think it's a casual way of using the expression *"au niveau de"* which is synonym to *"en terme de"*, *"concernant"*:

Other examples:

> Je ne suis pas très doué (au) niveau (de l') informatique et tout ça...
>
> Je n'y connais rien (au) niveau (de la) politique.

It's often used as an expression with *"à quel niveau ?"*:

> - J'essaie d'apprendre la guitare mais je bloque.
> - A quel niveau ?
> - Ben, tout ce qui est main gauche, je n'arrive pas à positionner mes doigts rapidement.

Comment: Hi. Dictionaries do not seem to cover this *abbreviated* use of "niveau" --
 which makes me wonder if this is a rather contemporary expression?

Comment: Contemporary, I don't know, spoken casual language, sure.

Comment: I find it interesting that this "niveau" expression takes away a definite article. By the way, do you think it's necessary to place a comma: "Je n'y connais rien, niveau politique"?

Comment: +1 for mentioning that sarcasm isn't necessarily a part of the expression (btw, should the "that" following "aspect" in your first sentence be there?). ... To @Alone-zee : I can’t find this abbreviated use of *niveau* discussed in dictionaries either, but it kind of reminds me of how “du côté de” (in the sense of “Sous l'aspect de, relativement à” discussed in a remark near the bottom of [this TLFi entry](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/c%C3%B4t%C3%A9)) is often found whittled down to “du côté” and even all the way to just “C/côté”  in casual speech.

Comment: Contemporary, if you consider anything after WWII say to be such. But clearly not used before, yes.  And also yes, the comma would be indispensable if you do away with the original little helper words.

Answer (score 3):

Your understandig of the use of the word *niveau* in this sentence is correct. Most of the times it appears as *au niveau de*.

The *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* notes this particular use of the word started to spread in the 1980s and it is open to debate.

> *Au niveau de* (suivi d'un nom abstrait) : dans le domaine de. *Au  niveau des intentions*, en ce qui concerne, pour ce qui est de ... (jargon psychologique). *Au niveau du vécu* : dans l'expérience vécue.

The [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/niveau) says:

> Hanse Nouv. 1983, note : ,,L'expression au niveau de est devenue un cliché dont on abuse et dont on déforme le sens. Elle signifie proprement : « à la hauteur de », « sur la même ligne que » (au propre et au figuré) et suppose donc une comparaison (...). Si l'on pense à des plans superposés, on peut dire, en distinguant par exemple la conception et l'expression : Au niveau du langage, une difficulté se présente (...). Mais on en est arrivé à employer au niveau de pour en ce qui concerne, du point de vue de, dans le domaine de, en matière de, pour, dans, etc. et à dire, par exemple : (...). *L'humour de cet auteur se manifeste au niveau du langage (...). Et même Au niveau de mes vaches!*``

The [Banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2916):

> **Au niveau de**
>   L’expression au niveau de est devenue un cliché. L’emploi abusif de cette locution lui a fait perdre son sens premier : au niveau de implique avant tout, au propre comme au figuré, l’idée d’élévation, de hauteur, de rang, de comparaison. Cette expression signifie « à la hauteur de, à la portée de, sur la même ligne que ».
>   Plusieurs emplois indus de cette expression empiètent en fait sur des emplois d’autres locutions : dans le domaine de, en matière de, du point de vue de, sur le plan de, au sujet de, pour ce qui est de, etc.
>
> Exemples :
>   - La doyenne a prévu de nouveaux programmes en matière de santé communautaire. (et non : au niveau de la santé communautaire)
>   - Dans le domaine de la production agricole, les prévisions budgétaires sont encourageantes. (et non : au niveau de la production agricole)
>   - Le talent de ce chercheur se manifeste surtout sur le plan de la synthèse. (et non : au niveau de la synthèse)

So I would only use *(au)niveau* with that sense in informal speech.  Still informal but not debated would be the use of *question* with the meaning of *en ce qui concerne/au sujet de*.([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/question) Fam. Question + nom en appos. avec omission de l'art. déf.*Question église, mariage, santé. Beaucoup de libérés vivent par deux − non pas (...) question relations sexuelles − non! mais pour s'entraider* (Dussort, *Journal*, 1930, dép. par G. Esnault, 1953, p. 6).
A still colloquial but less informal way to express this would be to use the word *rayon*. ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rayon) − Au fig. Espace, domaine où s'exerce l'activité de quelqu'un ou de quelque chose.)*

<sup>*Merci à Simon Deschamps pour l'avoir suggéré.</sup>

Comment: T'en connais un rayon niveau français.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Your saying "'en connais un rayon" made me realise that this "niveau" is also close to saying "T'en connais un rayon **en matière du** français", perhaps?

Comment: @Alone-zee Indeed I was in the process of editing my answer to add it,   after I'd read SimonDéchamps's comment.

Comment: @Alone-zee It's an exact synonym in casual French. But as Laure wrote, the origin of "niveau" should keep it for situations where you compare "levels" of things.

Comment: "Au niveau de (suivi d'un **nom abstrait**)": It just so happens that in my post I wrote "**everything** marriage" which is an expression used in everyday conversation but likely to be shunned by purists. The "niveau + un nom abstrait" construction may well be close  to this "**everything / all things** + un nom abstrait" expression in English in terms of construction.

Comment: @Alone-zee The fact that you don't find the mention of the use without definite article is that it is a fairly recent use and even with the definite article it is not widely accepted, whereas the use of *question* is not debated. I think the use of *question* would be closer to your use of "everything".